# jquery $empty not working with mobile detection

Tags: jquery

i am using a script that detects if the user is using a mobile device or not . I wanted to remove some specific content when the case is of mobile . I dont want to hide it using `display:none` as my content is using data foe a checkout which is also being used in web content so its like only one data content should be present if the user uses a mobile device or if he uses web . So its better to remove all the html and data if a mobile device is detected . I tried using `jquery empty` for that but its not working.

my script is

```
/**
 * jQuery.browser.mobile (http://detectmobilebrowser.com/)
 *
 * jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device
 *
 **/
(function(a){(jQuery.browser=jQuery.browser||{}).mobile=/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);

if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
   alert("mobile");
}
else
{
    $('.mobile_content').empty();
    alert("web");   
}
```

`$('.mobile_content').empty();` should empty the html but its not doing so. Btw the script works fine it alerts if its a mobile device or web.

html to be emptied

```
                <div class="mobile_content">
                <!--------------------------------------your info---------------------------------------->
                    <div class="grey_bar">

                        <span>Your Info</span>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Billing Address</h1>
                    <p>Please use the address that appears on your credit card statement. Incomplete or incorrect information may result in a delay or cancellation of your order.</p>
                    <p><b>*Required Fields</b></p>
                    <div class="form">
                        <div class="row_mobile">
                            <p>*First Name</p>
                            <input type="text" value="" name="" class="mobile_textbox" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row_mobile">
                            <p>*Last Name</p>
                            <input type="text" value="" name="" class="mobile_textbox" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row_mobile">
                            <p>*Address</p>
                            <input type="text" value="" name="" class="mobile_textbox" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row_mobile">
                            <p style="font-weight:normal;">Address Line 2(optional)</p>
                            <input type="text" value="" name="" class="mobile_textbox" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row_mobile">
                            <div class="row_mobile_left">
                                <p>*City</p>
                                <input type="text" value="" name="" class="mobile_textbox" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: try using $("item").html("");

Comment: I did try using this but still it didnt worked. Its strange i have checked dom for errors too. But no errors found

Comment: You want to remove content when on mobile, but you're conditional statement shows the opposite: you remove the mobile content when NOT on mobile.

Comment: Yes i am testing it for now on web . The thing is `empty` is not working . i guess my code is right but its not working

Comment: post your html, I bet the problem is there :) Is mobile_content an ID that has to be written as $("#mobile_content")?

Comment: the html is too big and the mobile_content is a class. that is the most common mistake i checked that first lol

Comment: Well we cant help without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: wait ill paste some of it.

Comment: Is the javascript above the html? Is the dom ready when you're running this code?

Comment: How about `$('.mobile_content').remove()` instead? Or is it necessary that you keep an empty `<div class="mobile_content"></div>` in the DOM?

Comment: no it is not required to keep it in dom but have tried remove too , didnt helped me

Comment: @user1001176 Wrap your if statement in a domready callback (you need to imagine the newlines obv.): ```$(function() { if(…)});```. And did you try to run ```empty()``` from your browsers console? On a sidenote: you can always create an example @ jsFiddle or JSBin for us.